# baudrate calculation from frame timings

Tags: serial, embedded, baudrate, serial-bus

I'm working to interface with an old serial protocol.
All I have actually is the frame format and various timings.

I need the baudrate to sync correctly and use the data properly.

- My frame is 15 bits (one start, 12 data, one parity, one stop)
- One bit is held for 10ms
- One frame is 150ms
- (spec says 4ms between frame, I think this is useless and it's just the change-time-rising stuff from/to 0/1)

I tried to find some calculations on the web but found nothing...

Any help for that?

Thanks.

Comment: The baud rate is the inverse of the period, so for a 10ms period the baud rate is 100. That said, I doubt you'll find a (hardware) serial port implementation that will deal with a frame of that size. You'll probably need to write a soft UART in an MCU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Baud rate is the inverse of a single (data) bit time.  So the start, stop, or other framing doesn't actually come into the calculation.

So, the answer for you is simply 100 Baud.